How can I copy/paste a google sheet directly into another folder?
We use Google Sheets as quotation calculators.
We plan to have a folder Templates with some calculators depending on the products and have the agents to be able to copy that template in their working directories inside the Google Drive.
Now the process is:

Make a copy
Move the file

This has several drawbacks:

The template folder must be writeable for all the agents
The file gets created with another name (Copy of ...)
The move functionality of Google Drive is far from intuitive.

In a normal filesystem, the user would do this:

Open both folders (templates + working dir)
Copy from templates, paste in the working dir.

Question
Can this simple "duplicate this file in this other folder" be done in Google Drive?
Otherwise, if not, can it be done in NextCloud?

The simplest approach might be to focus on this from the Google Sheets sharing level rather than focusing on Google Drive access and permissions.
If you shared the templates (spreadsheets) with the agents from Sheets with read-only permissions, the templates would show up in the agents' own Drive folders as well as Google Sheets, under "Shared with me".
You could additionally provide a list of links to the templates in a document if useful.
To get a writable version of a template, an agent would:

Open one of the read-only templates
Select Make a copy from the File menu
Agent would then Name it as they wish and save it to any Folder they want

The copy would now be writable (no longer read-only)

